# Replace capital letter with same letter but curly brackets surrounding the letter: Sun => {S}un

Tags: replace, ms-word, latex, notepad++, text-editor

How can I easily (Word, Notepad++, Wordpad etc.) replace the capital letter in words with the same letter surrounded by curly brackets? I'm editing a jabref LaTeX file where this has to be done to capital letters.

Example:
Today is Monday and tomorrow will be Tuesday. YAY! => {T}oday is {M}onday and tomorrow will be {T}uesday. {Y}{A}{Y}!

I tried doing this with the wildcards in Word and Notepad++ but failed. At the moment I'm doing this manually which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not how to use software such as Word etc. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

However, as you are new: this can easily be done using wildcards in Word:

[image]

Comment: Why are you answering an off topic question? Providing such answers just encourages people to ask more off topic questions.

Comment: Feel free to delete this topic. Thanks a thousand times for answering but adrian does have a point.